# Style two stripe checkout (simple integration) buttons differently on same page

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I' using stripe checkout' simple integration, i.e.

```
<form action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
<script
  src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
  data-key="key_example"
  data-amount="2000"
  data-name="test"
  data-description="2 widgets"
  data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
  data-locale="auto"
  data-currency="aud">
</script>
</form>
```

To style the button that triggers the initial pop up i know I need to override the .stripe-button-el span class however, I've got two stripe checkout buttons (a choice of two subscriptions) on the same page and want to style them differently (i.e. have different backgrounds). Anyone know how i can do this?

(I cant seem to work out their custom integration so please don't suggest this)

Thanks!

Comment: You should not try to override Checkout's default CSS or style. This is not reliable and if Stripe changes their code/logic then yours break. You should use Custom Checkout because that's the reason it was built. I understand that's not what you want to hear but that's the right way. If you're stuck with Custom Checkout, take the time to write to Stripe's support team with your code and they will help you: https://support.stripe.com/email